# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC redirect the users to subdomain based on Azure AD group

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core-mvc, subdomain, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to write an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller method in C# that will redirect the Azure AD authenticated user to the subdomain based on Azure AD group assigned to the user.

Can any expert advise me on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You will need to create a middleware to parse the identity claims, then redirect to a corresponding URL.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to get the Azure group ID, because the token doesn't support sending group names, so you have to use the id to distinguish.
[image]

After yuo creat a client in the app registeration, go the client "Token configuration" add the group information to the claim
[image]

Then you could test with create a MVC template project with  "Microsoft identity platform" authentication type.
[image]
Fill the client information in appsettings.
[image]

Create a `CustomMiddleware.cs` (Modify the `usergroups.Contains("group id")` to your groupid, and modify the redirect domian )

```
    public class CustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var usergroups = new List<string>();
            var claims = httpContext.User.Claims;
            foreach (var c in claims)
            {
                if (c.Type == "groups")
                {
                    usergroups.Add(c.Value);
                }
            }
            if (usergroups.Contains("{group id}"))
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com"); //change to the corresponding subdomain.
            }
                
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.  
    public static class CustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

add the middleware to program.cs

```
...
app.UseCustomMiddleware();
app.Run();
```

Then if the login user has the {gourp id} claim, the user will be redirect.

Comment: Thank you, Qiang. It's really helpful for me. Actually,  I need to render the Power BI report on the subdomain site. Is there any way I can pass the same authentication token over there?